# How to access multiple tab with URL + variable in Java Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I need to open over 100 pages (https://same URL/"different page") and I want to use for loop with variable to open a certain amount of them at once.
I wrote below code in Java selenium but got an error: **javascript error: missing ) after argument list**

Could someone help me to figure out where went wrong please? Thank you.

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

public class multibrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String url = "https://www.abc/";
        

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.location = \'" + url + "\'");
        
        new Click().clickElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[title=123']")));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("Loading time longer than 15 seconds");
        }
        
         // create list
        List<String> crunchifyList = new ArrayList<String>();
 
        // add 2 different values to list
        crunchifyList.add("123");
        crunchifyList.add("456");
 
        //For loop
        for (int i = 0; i < crunchifyList.size(); i++) {
            js.executeScript("window.open('https://www.abc/' + crunchifyList.get(i) +', '_blank');");
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `crunchifyList.get(i)` is surrounded by double quotes - making it (part of) a string literal. Compare with this: `js.executeScript("window.open('https://www.abc/'" + crunchifyList.get(i) + "', '_blank');");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed quotes(""), should be:

```
js.executeScript("window.open('https://www.abc/'" + crunchifyList.get(i) + "', '_blank');");
```